# How to pass NULL value to ValuesAttribute of the test method?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

When I try to pass Null value to nunit ValuesAttribute I get an error.

If will run this test, all test methods of the class will`t be executed:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UrlSectionsTests {

    [Test]
    public void SetRoot_Throws_ArgumentNullExcpetion(
        [Values(null)] TestUrlRootSection rootSection
        )
    {
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => 
            this.urlSections.Root = rootSection);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pass NULL value to ValuesAttribute?

Comment: What error do you get? Also, do you need to use the attribute if testing for null? I mean you can just assign null to `Root` and pass the test if exception is thrown.

Comment: @CodingYoshi When I try to run this test I doesn't  get any error messages. It just don`t work. And also this test class doesn't display at the test explorer.

Comment: Put `[TestFixture]` on top of your class.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Sorry, forget to put it in my example. But I have It in my code.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @CodingYoshi VisualStudio doesn't show any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ValuesAttribute` type has a constructor overload with signature `ValuesAttribute(params object[] x)`, that overload will preferred in its non-expanded form.  I.e., your bare `null` will be seen as a `null` of type `object[]`. To avoid that, use:

```
[Values((object)null)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with CodingYoshi that you don't have much reason to use `ValuesAttribute` here. However, you may have uncovered a bug, in which case it should be reported and fixed!

Comment: I prefer to use this attribute. It gives me opportunity to save original method signature in my test method. I mean, that It gives me opportunity to see parameters that should be passed to the method. (Thank you for your answer!)

Answer (score 1):

You better use an appropriate tests naming conventions such as `UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()`. In this particular case you may rename function to `Root_SetToNull_ThrowsArgumentNullExcpetion()`. Check [Naming standards for unit tests](http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html) article by Roy Osherove for more information.

If you try to run this test case using [NUnit Console Runner](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Runner) you will see that exception is thrown by NUnit Framework:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at NUnit.Framework.Internal.ParamAttributeTypeConversions.GetData(Object[] data, Type targetType)
>      at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.ParameterDataSourceProvider.GetDataFor(IParameterInfo parameter)
>      at NUnit.Framework.CombiningStrategyAttribute.BuildFrom(IMethodInfo method, Test suite)
>      at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.DefaultTestCaseBuilder.BuildFrom(IMethodInfo method, Test parentSuite)
>      at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.AddTestCasesToFixture(TestFixture fixture)
>      at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.BuildFrom(ITypeInfo typeInfo)
>      at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Builders.DefaultSuiteBuilder.BuildFrom(ITypeInfo typeInfo)

This is probably a bug. But I don't see any strong reason to use `[Values(null)]` anyway, because you can safely turn any test case parameter that is always `null` to local variable or remove entirely.

Comment: I don't understand how to use name conventions when method have three or more parameters. I mean that it looks VERY inconvenient. In such cases the name of the of the method starts to look to long and unreadable. That`s why I try to put all parameters values out of the method name using such instrument as [Values(null)]. (Thank you for your reply) I know that I have to follow name conventions but, but when I see those long names =/

Comment: Typically function name doesn't include actual argument values. It's just happens to be that in this particular case argument value is the best description of `StateUnderTest`. Most of the time you associate single test function with multiple `TestCaseAttribute` or function parameters with `ValuesAttribute` instances. And you include summary of that test cases in function name rather than actual argument values. For example test cases may include multiple different schemes, authorities, paths, queries and fragments all of which you can sum-up as `ValidUri`.

Comment: A good argument values summary can give reader better understanding of the condition that this unit of work is tested in. Because it can be hard to understand from values themselves. For example check [UriIPv4Host_BadAddresses_AllFail()](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/016659c6631ba8f21c359c15a3c6bb5d2a37f322/src/System.Private.Uri/tests/FunctionalTests/UriIpHostTest.cs#L132) from .NET Core Libraries. Obviously, you don't have to follow any naming convention that doesn't work for you and your team =)